# Paypal rest api: Show order details on side of approval page not in a dropdown box. (python)

Tags: python, rest, paypal

I'm currently using the rest api and the sandbox site for testing. I'm using paypalrestsdk for python.

I can send a payment through to completion so my code works fine.  However we don't want the order details showing up in this little dropdown box shown in my picture, but on the side in a box like a normal paypal checkout.

How can I change this dropdown cart to a sideview cart?  [image]